# Sum of log over friables

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers.
What is the mean value of the function $\log$ on $y$ friables integers  less than $x$ i.e the value of the following sum
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ P(n)\leq y}} \log(n),$$
where $P(n)$ is the greatest prime factor of $n.$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be close to $K(y)x\log(x/e)$ with $K(y)$ a version of Dickman's constant.  (Maybe $K(\log y/\log x)$ is more standard.) You might get some improvement by a clever pairing of smooth numbers, say log(m)d(m)/2 for m a certain smooth number m larger than x. This might get you most of the sum, and then you can approximate the rest with a small multiple of log x.  Gerhard "Or Try Two Large Smooths" Paseman, 2018.08.09.

Comment: I'd never heard the term 'friable' for integers before.  Is 'smooth' used interchangeably with 'friable'?  (Perhaps it's a matter of linguistic background, since the paper you cite [below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307911) is in French?)

Comment: @LSpice: Some people prefer friable, as the word smooth already carries too many different meanings. For others friable sounds too much like fryable.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta, well, there’s no denying that ‘friable’ is a much mathematically rarer term (as well as being quite apposite).  In my field, we have the very inventive term ‘good’.  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De La Breteche and Tenenbaum established in their paper **'Propriétés statistiques des entiers friables'** the asymptotic formula for the above sum. They find it as a corollary; Uniformly for $2 \leq y \leq x,$ we have 
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ P(n)\leq y}} \log(n)=\left\{\log(x)-\frac{\log(y)+O(\log\log(y))}{\log\left(1+\frac{y}{\log(x)}\right)} \right\}\Psi(x,y),$$
where $\Psi(x,y)$ is the number of friables integers less than $x$ whose greatest  prime factors are less than $y.$